# Is MATLAB row specific or column major?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, we can operate on both rows and columns of a matrix. What does it exactly mean by "row major" or "column major"?

Comment: Do you mean "row major" and "column major"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is important to understand that MATLAB stores data in [*column-major* order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order#Column-major_order), so you know what happens when you apply the `colon` operator without any commas:

```
>> M = magic(3)
M =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
>> M(:)
ans =
     8
     3
     4
     1
     5
     9
     6
     7
     2
```

I tend to think "MATLAB goes down, then across". This makes it easy to `reshape` and `permute` arrays without scrambling your data.  It's also necessary in order to grasp *linear indexing* (e.g. `M(4)`).

For example, a common way to obtain a column vector inline from some expression that generates an array is:

```
reshape(<array expression>,[],1)
```

As with `(:)` this stacks all the columns on top of each other into single column vector, for all data in any higher dimensions.
 But this nifty syntactic trick lets you avoid an extra line of code.

Comment: that simple sentence "MATLAB goes down, then across", has FINALLY given me a way to remember MATLAB's indexing rules. I have been trying to remember for over 6 years this simple fact lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In MATLAB, arrays are stored in **column major order**.

It means that when you have a multi-dimensional array, its 1D representation in memory is such that leftmost indices change faster.

It's called *column* major order because for a 2D array (matrix), the first (leftmost) index is typically the row index, so since it changes faster than the second (next to the right) index, the 1D representation of the matrix is memory correspond to the concatenation of the *columns* of the matrix.