# How Matlab extract a subset of a bigger matrix by specifying the indices?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A

A =

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
16    17    18    19    20
```

i have another matrix to specify the indices

index =

```
 1     2
 3     4
```

Now, i have got third matrix C from A

```
C = A(index)
```

C =

```
 1     6
11    16
```

**Problem:** I am unable to understand how come i have received such a matrix`C`. I mean, what is logi behind it?

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413164/is-matlab-row-specific-or-column-specific).

Answer (score 4):

The logic behind it is [***linear indexing***](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html): When you provide a single index, Matlab moves along columns first, then along rows, then along further dimensions (according to their order).

So in  your case (4 x 5 matrix) the entries of `A` are being accessed in the following order (each number here represents order, not the value of the entry):

```
 1     5     9    13    17
 2     6    10    14    18
 3     7    11    15    19
 4     8    12    16    20
```

Once you get used to it, you'll see linear indexing is a very powerful tool.

As an example: to obtain the maximum value in `A` you could just use `max(A(1:20))`. This could be further simplified to `max(A(1:end))` or `max(A(:))`. Note that "`A(:)`" is a common Matlab idiom, used to turn any array into a column vector; which is sometimes called *linearizing* the array.

See also [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) and [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html),  which are used to convert from linear index to standard indices and vice versa.