# Median of an ENTIRE multi-dimensional array (not of just one dimension) in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, median

I have a 10 x 10 array of values, `A`. I need the median, `M`, of all of those values.  I can find the medians along the rows or along the columns easily:

```
M = median(A,1) %or
M = median(A,2)
```

However, `M = median(A)` also returns the medians along the rows.

How can I find a single median of ALL the values?   I know I could convert the array to one very very long vector, but that seems unpleasant and inefficient. Is there a simpler solution? I would like to be able to do this for multi-dimensional arrays as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Converting a matrix to a single vector is one of the **fastest** operations you can perform in MATLAB.  Remember that memory in MATLAB is arranged in column-major order and so actually using multiple dimension access indices to get the right memory location is syntactic sugar to multidimensionally access an element with a single index.  Luis's suggestion below to unroll the matrix into a long vector and performing the median... you can't get it any faster.

Comment: Perfect! I overestimated the time-consuming-ness of converting. Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer by Luis to let the community know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First linearize by indexing with `(:)`. This transforms any array into a column array. Then compute the median:

```
M = median(A(:));
```

I don't think that indexing with `(:)` needs any memory reallocation. It just reads the array in [column-major](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413441/2586922) order.

Comment: There's really no other answer than this one. +1.