# Adjusting a double array - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I adjust the boundary double array that looks like that:

```
102     8
101     9
100     9
99      9
…       …
```

To be a double array that looks like this:

```
102   8   101   9   100   9   99   9 … …
```

Code:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
boundary = B{1}
```

Comment: `boundary = reshape(boundary.',1,[])`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413164/is-matlab-row-specific-or-column-specific

Answer (score 0):

```
% consider A is your matrix.
At=A.';
At(:)  % this matrix will give what you want.
```