# Without for loop, can I generate list [1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5 ...] in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Unlike Python, MATLAB list generation expression is limited. In MATLAB I am only allowed to do a:b:c. Can I generate a list [1 2 3  2 3 4  3 4 5 ...] in MATLAB without using for loop?

Answer (score 7):

```
N = 3;
M = 4;
result = reshape((1:N).'+(0:M-1), 1, []);
```

gives

```
result =
     1     2     3     2     3     4     3     4     5     4     5     6
```

#### How it works

`(1:N).'+(0:M-1)` uses [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) to create the `M`×`N` matrix

```
 1     2     3   ...  M
 2     3     4   ...  M+1
 3     4     5   ...  M+2
   ...
 N     N+1   N+2 ...  N+M-1
```

Then `reshape(..., 1, [])` reshapes this matrix into a row vector, reading the elements in [column-major order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21413164/2586922) (down, then across).

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make three lists `[1,2,3...], [2,3,4...] and [3,4,5...]` and `interleave` them. Alternatively, you can take advantage of the pattern: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]-[0,0,0,2,2,2,4,4,4]=[1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]`. The `repelem()` function is useful for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cell2mat` + `arrayfun` like belwn

```
n = 3;
m = 3;
res = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x+(1:n),1:m,'UniformOutput',false));
```

such that

```
res =

   2   3   4   3   4   5   4   5   6
```