# Make array in Matlab using elements from another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to build an arrangement from the elements of two other arrangements. With the following code an array is generated but only with the last two values of X and Y.

```
    X = [0  7.313   14.632  18.238  18.308  18.383  18.394  18.395  18.395  18.395  18.395]
        Y = [10.882 18.276  21.939  22.018  22.093  22.105  22.106  22.106  22.106  22.106 22.106]

        Z = zeros(22,1) ;

        for i = 1:2:22
            for j = 2:2:22
               for m = 1:11
                   for n = 1:11

            Z(i,:) = X(:,m) ;
            Z(j,:) = Y(:,n) ;

                   end
               end
            end
        end

    output: Z = 18.395
                22.106
                18.395
                22.106
                18.395
                22.106
                ...
```

But I need to get the Z array as follows:

```
expected output: Z = X(1)
                     Y(1)
                     X(2)
                     Y(2)
                     X(3)
                     Y(3)
                     ...

with the values: Z = 0
                     10.882
                     7.313
                     18.276
                     14.632
                     21.939
                     ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what's the desired output exactly in this example?

Comment: Because your code does not do what you want it to do, you need to make it clear what the aim of the code was. "index each element of X and Y to the Z array" is not at all clear. Please [edit] your question to include the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited the question including the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate `X` and `Y` vertically and then [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) into a column. The values are read in [column-major order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21413164/2586922), which gives the desired result:

```
Z = reshape([X; Y], [], 1);
```