# How to make a third matrix with exclusive values from two other matrices, with multiple columns?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to make a new matrix of n rows and 7 columns, but my code only outputs the first column.

```
%sample values
table_a = [161.0972   11.0000   14.0000    1.0000         0         0         0;
  163.0401    9.0000    8.0000    3.0000         0         0         0;
  163.0765   10.0000   12.0000    2.0000         0         0         0;
  163.1129   11.0000   16.0000    1.0000         0         0         0;
  165.0194    8.0000    6.0000    4.0000         0         0         0;
  165.0558    9.0000   10.0000    3.0000         0         0         0;
  165.0922   10.0000   14.0000    2.0000         0         0         0]
  
table_b = [163.0401    9.0000    8.0000    3.0000         0         0         0;
  163.0765   10.0000   12.0000    2.0000         0         0         0;
  165.0558    9.0000   10.0000    3.0000         0         0         0;
  165.0922   10.0000   14.0000    2.0000         0         0         0;
  167.0350    8.0000    8.0000    4.0000         0         0         0;
  167.0714    9.0000   12.0000    3.0000         0         0         0;
  169.0143    7.0000    6.0000    5.0000         0         0         0]


table_c = table_a(~ismember(table_a(:, 1:7), table_b(:, 1:7)));
```

This is what I yield:

```
table_c =
163.0401    
163.0765  
165.0922
```

This is what I expect to yield:

```
table_c = 
163.0401    9.0000    8.0000    3.0000         0         0         0
163.0765   10.0000   12.0000    2.0000         0         0         0
165.0922   10.0000   14.0000    2.0000         0         0         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently does this:

```matlab
filter = ~ismember(table_a(:, 1:7), table_b(:, 1:7));
table_c = table_a(filter);
```

This selects all `table_a(x)` that have `filter(x) = true`.

You want to select the *rows* of `table_a` that fulfill the condition, but select all columns of those rows.
To do this, you have to tell Matlab to select those rows, and *all columns* of `table_a`

```
table_c = table_a(filter, :);
```

Or in one line,

```
table_c = table_a(~ismember(table_a(:, 1:7), table_b(:, 1:7)), :);
```

To clarify, Matlab stores its 2D arrays as [column-major arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413164/is-matlab-row-specific-or-column-specific). With a matrix

```matlab
A = [0, 1, 2;
     3, 4, 5;
     6, 7, 8];
```

`A(i)` selects the `i`th element in the column-major-ordered array, so `A(4)` would give you `1`. `A(i, j)` selects the `i`th row and `j`th column of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and you described it so simply.